# How to change SwiftUI view if location services are not enabled

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

How do you change the current view of a project when location services are not allowed by the user.

Currently I have it set up like this:

```
{
 
    
    @Published var location: CLLocation? = nil
    @Published var locationAllowed:Bool = false
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthoization status: CLAuthorizationStatus, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      guard let location = locations.last else { return }
         switch status {
             case .restricted, .denied:
                // Disable your app's location features
                locationAllowed = false
                
                break;
                   
             case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                // Enable your app's location features.
                locationAllowed = true
                break;
                   
             case .authorizedAlways:
                // Enable or prepare your app's location features that can run any time.
                locationAllowed = true
                break;
                   
             case .notDetermined:
                locationAllowed = true
                break;
          }
        self.location = location
    }


}
```

Where the variable locationAllowed is a published variable. So how would I go about changing the view depending on the value of locationAllowed. I attempted to do it from the SceneDelagate:

```
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            
            let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
            var contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)
            
            if (LocationManager().$locationAllowed == false){
                contentView = LocationNotAllowedView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, managedObjectContext)            }
            
            
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

This just threw a compiler error. My other idea was to have a state variable in the ContentView() and just change the view to my other view when it read false, but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it using optional view inside contentView since you had publisher

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct test: View {
        
        @ObservedObject var worker = locationManager()
        
        var body: some View {
            HStack {
                optionalLocation.init(allowed: worker.isAllowed)
            }
        }
        
    }


    struct optionalLocation: View {
        
        var allowed: Bool?
        
        var body: some View {
            if let allowed = self.allowed, allowed {
                return AnyView(
                    Text("Its Allowed!")
                )
            } else {
                return AnyView(
                    Text("Not Allowed")
                )
            }
        }
        
    }
```